# Jquery: What is the difference between stop(true) and clearQueue()

Tags: jquery

What is the difference between using a `stop()` with the `clearQueue` parameter set to true and just using the `clearqueue()`, and if there is no difference why both?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the api docs, `.stop()` is meant only for animation, however `.clearqueue()` will remove *any* function attached to a standard jquery queue.

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/):

> When the .clearQueue() method is
>   called, all functions on the queue
>   that have not been executed are
>   removed from the queue. When used
>   without an argument, .clearQueue()
>   removes the remaining functions from
>   fx, the standard effects queue. In
>   this way it is similar to .stop(true).
>   However, while the .stop() method is
>   meant to be used only with animations,
>   .clearQueue() can also be used to
>   remove any function that has been
>   added to a generic jQuery queue with
>   the .queue() method.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery supports a number of queues, the most common of which is the `fx` queue for animations. `.stop()` works only on the `fx` queue, while `clearQueue` lets you specify some other (custom) queue.

---

Here is an example with a custom queue:

```
// First function to queue
function a1(next) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        alert("one");
        next();
    }, 1000);
}

// Second function to queue
function a2(next) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        alert("two");
        next();
    }, 1000);
}

// Queue both functions and start it off
$('body').queue('alerts', a1).queue('alerts', a2).dequeue('alerts');

// Clear the queue to prevent the second alert from showing
$('body').clearQueue('alerts');
```

See the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cwbkQ/).